# MFC: Can't load from StringTable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have next data in string table:

```
    IDS_TEXT1 "some tesxt1"
IDS_TEXT2 "some tesxt2"
```

and I am loading it by using:

```
    std::wstring call; 
WCHAR wsBuf[1024];
if (size_t len = ::LoadStringW(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), IDS_TEXT1, (PWCHAR)&wsBuf, sizeof(wsBuf)))
    call.assign(wsBuf, len);
```

but LoadStringW fails returns empty string for me (wsBuf == NULL), any ideas where is error?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say?

Comment: Try NULL as first `LoadStringW` parameter. BTW, divide `sizeof(wsBuf)` by `sizeof(WCHAR)`

Comment: GetLastError() returns ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND, but it is in *.rc file and resources.h file

Comment: @Ted, and the string resources are stored in the executable itself, not in a satellite DLL?

Comment: Got it GetModuleHandle() should be GetModuleHandle(L"my.dll") not GetModuleHandle(NULL)

Comment: You should put your own commet as answer.